# CDI - Bean name is ambiguous

Tags: java, cdi

I've defined two Bean:

```
@Named("mysql")
public MySqlLogService extends AbstractLogService { ... }

@Named("mysql")
public MySqlConcurrencyService implements ConcurrencyService { ... }
```

I supposed the `Named` qualifier was somehow related to the type of the Bean, however Weld returns:

```
Caused by: org.jboss.weld.exceptions.DeploymentException: WELD-001414: Bean name is ambiguous. Name mysql resolves to beans: 
  - Managed Bean [class my.package.MySqlConcurrencyService] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any],
  - Managed Bean [class my.other.package.MySqlLogService] with qualifiers [@Default @Named @Any]
```

Why? What's the scope of qualifiers?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot have the same bean name (via `@Named`) for two enabled beans, no matter the type.

And since it is a CDI, how about we look at CDI specification?
Let's start with [2.6. Bean names](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#names), where it states:

> ... A bean with a name may be referred to by its name when used in a non typesafe environment (like the Unified Expression Language)....

So you are able to use that bean with no reference to its type. Hence the requirement to be able to resolve bean name to one particular bean.The use case is, for instance, when you are using EL from JSF pages.

A bit further on, it reads:

> Subject to the restrictions defined in [Ambiguous names](http://docs.jboss.org/cdi/spec/2.0/cdi-spec.html#ambig_names), multiple beans may share the same bean name.

This allows you to actually "break" the uniqueness of the name so long as you can guarantee that by the end of typesafe resolution, only one bean will be found with that given name.

Make sure your beans have unique names and it will work.
If it is only qualifiers you are after, then using `@Named` brings in overhead you probably don't need. Just create your own qualifier and go from there.

Comment: Thanks, as always.

Answer (score 2):

Seems that you are confusing the CDI annotations. The `@Named("my_custom_name")` annotation is used to refer to that class/impl explicitly like :

```
@Inject
@Named("my_custom_name")
ConcurrencyService service;
```

In case you weren't defining a custom name inside the `@Named` then by default its picking up the class name , so you would't face that error.
In your example :

```
@Named
MySqlLogService
```

Would be refered as `mySqlLogService` and

```
@Named
MySqlConcurrencyService
```

Would be refered as `mySqlConcurrencyService` , but still i dont get what you're trying to achieve.

The scope its not defined with the `@Named` but instead by using :

```
@RequestScoped
@SessionScoped
@ApplicationScoped
@ConversationScoped
```

More info [here](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/articles/java/cdi-javaee-bien-225152.html) and here are 2 examples [i](https://memorynotfound.com/cdi-managed-bean-example-with-named/) [ii](https://dzone.com/articles/java-ee6-cdi-named-components)

For the Scopes check the oracle's [page](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/tutorial/doc/gjbbk.html)

Also a nice blog explaining the [Qualifiers](https://blogs.oracle.com/arungupta/totd-161:-java-ee-6-cdi-qualifiers-explained-default,-any,-new,-named)

Comment: These two beans are produced by instance.select() passing a NamedLiteral, having the string argument from a properties file (mysql, SQL server, etc)

Comment: What I'm wondering is why the names collide if the types hierarchies are different.

Comment: well cannot find any document related with that question , but if you deep search it a bit , inside jboss modules , there is(might be) a map holding the bean definition and the actual <key> is the name you are providing , thus you are getting this exception

Comment: Yes I already debugged Weld. Can't understand, I thought qualifiers were to be specified when implementing multiple times the SAME interface

Comment: The same interface , that's correct , but apparently the name will be used as the key to fetch the proper instance from Bean Map/Cache. The same applies to Spring DI if you are familiar with.

Comment: Yes I'm familiar! I just replaced the @Named qualifier with a custom one [@Database("...")] and the problem is gone ;)